# How can I relocate MP4 files from one location to another?

Tags: windows, vba, powershell

I have a bunch of pictures and videos mixed in with each other on my external hard drive, and I want to move all video files from one location to another whilst keeping the same structure. Is this possible to to achieve without changing the current structure with the images? Example below:

[image: Folder Structure Example]

Comment: The `Folder Path` is the same in all 3 tables in your picture?

Comment: Ops thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the picture :)

Comment: Of course it's possible, so that answers that question. Now what is your real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the folders are in the root you can't use a top level folder and use where PSPath so instead try this:

```
gci 'C:\Folder A' | ? {$_.Extension -eq '.MP4'} | Move-Item -Destination 'D:\Folder A'
gci 'C:\Folder B' | ? {$_.Extension -eq '.MP4'} | Move-Item -Destination 'D:\Folder B'
```

That should move all the MP4 files to D:\ and leave behing JPEGs in C:\

Answer (score 0):

The diagram shows that they are on the C drive (usualy not an External Drive) and only have a single directory. If this is th case, you would simple sort by File Type inside the Windows Explorer. A lot of information missing and the diagram doesn't seem to be what you are actually asking.

The diagram says the following:

```
"C:\Folder A\Image 1.jpg" move to "C:\Folder A\Image 1.jpg"
"C:\Folder B\Image 4.jpg" move to "C:\Folder B\Image 4.jpg"
```

As you can see this is redundant, because the file is already located in the path you want it to go to.

You just want to move the .MP4 files to the D drive.

```
"C:\Folder A\Video 1.MP4" move to "D:\Folder A\Video 1.MP4"
"C:\Folder A\Video 1.MP4" move to "D:\Folder B\Video 1.MP4"
```

If you wanted to keep the file structure naming the same. You would have to do something like this, but your question makes no sense. This is me trying to understand what you are trying to say without you telling us that you are downloading illegally, and that you want to cleanup.

```
# Variables
$sourcePath = 'Z:\Folder A'
$destPath = 'X:\Folder A'

# Movie folder Structure and File type
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Include '*.MP4' | Foreach-Object `
    {
        $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -Replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)
        if (!(Test-Path $destDir))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir | Out-Null
        }
        # Backup Files
        #Copy-Item $_ -Destination $destDir

        # Move Files
        #Move-Item $_ -Destination $destDir
    }
```